# Using jquery to submit one form on page that shares element names with other forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

To give you the most basic view of my question, I'm trying to create a page that is very similar to how facebook and twitter's dashboards and comment systems work. You have one page that will continuously create form elements (posts) from database rows in a loop as the user scrolls down. Users will then be able to comment on each of these posts. I want to be able to use ajax to submit comments on each post individually without reloading the page.

I run into a problem where when I try to submit a comment on any form other than the first one that is loaded on the page. In addition the ajax only posts the first form elements on submit (due to each form and elements having the same name I'm guessing).
Below is my comment loading script: [forgive the old php, I know I need to update it to mysqli or PDO]

php

```
<?php ... 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo "
  <div name='comment_body'>
  <form name='comment_form'>
  <td>User: ".$row['user']."</td>
  <td>Post: ".$row['post']."</td>
  <textarea name='comment'></textarea>
  <p name='post_id' style='display:none;'>".$row['post_id']."</p>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
  </form>
  ";
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = $row['post_id']");
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
  echo "
  <td>User: ".$row2['user']."</td>
  <td>Comment: ".$row2['comment']."</td>
  </div>
  ";
}
... ?>
```

jscript

```
<script>
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax ({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'submit_comment.php',
    data: {comment : $('#comment').val(), post_id : $('#post_id').text()}
    success: function() {
      $("#comment_body").load("load_comments.php #comment_body");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The script works to a point because when I comment on the first post, it works as expected. I just can't seem to figure out how to target the forms further down the page individually. Here's an example:

The very top post has a post_id value of 40. If I comment on post_id = 38, ajax will submit the empty comment field and post_id = 40 into the database.

Any help with the script form targeting would be great. If I need to rebuild my php query to give each echoed form element an individual name, that's fine as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this `$('.comment_form')` and `<form name='comment_form'>` you need to either give it a class `<form class='comment_form'>` or an id `$('#comment_form')` - `<form id='comment_form'>`

Comment: you also don't have matching ID's for your elements.

Comment: There is really so little thats right with this code its almost impossible to suggest anything other than a complete Refactoring

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're trying to send to in the ajax call is using:

```
$('#comment').val(), post_id : $('#post_id').text()
```

But your HTML doesn't have anything with an ID="comment" and ID="post_id". (the '#' in your selector means getElementById.) So you aren't sending any data to your php page. You need to use the correct selectors to get that data. (see below)

Get rid of the 'form' tags you don't need them. Change your

```
<input type="submit">
```

to a:

```
<input type="button" class="comment-submit">
```

Then your script can be:

```
<script>
$('.comment-submit').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get a referenct to this particular comment_body div
  var $commentbody = $(this).closest('.comment_body');
  // find the textarea within this particular comment_body
  var commenttext = $commentbody.find('textarea[name="comment"]').val();
  // find the post_id paragraph within this particular comment_body
  var postId = $commentbody.find('p[name="post_id"]').text();

  $.ajax ({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'submit_comment.php',
    data: {comment : commenttext , post_id : postId}
    success: function() {
      $comment_body.load("load_comments.php #comment_body");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Frankly I'm not sure what your success function is trying to do. But I think you need to work on it too. Normally an ajax call will return data so your success function should have a return value and that would be used to populate some part of your screen. The jQuery 'load()' function is another ajax call inside the success callback of an ajax call. I really don't think you want or need to do this.

Comment: Excellent solution. This worked perfectly. It was my fault for the bad example (I just typed a new one rather than copying my current code, so I did already have ID fields with matching names). I'll take a further look at the success function though. I'm just referencing a separate page that is essentially the same php and inserting the results into that div. There's got to be an easier way though haha. Thanks again!

Comment: FYI - if you have multiple fields on the page with ID="comments" and ID="post_id" then you have an invalid HTML page. You cannot have the same ID on any 2 elements in the same document. You should remove the ID's and just use the names.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select a unique form by class because your class is identical across all forms. Add an "id" field to the form element like this:

```
"<form name='comment_form' id='"+ .$row['id'] +"'>"
```

Then select a given form using that unique ID, and add your event handler. This must be in the same scope as you define your form. Like this:

```
$('#'+ .$row["id"]).on('submit', function (e) {
  //Handle the event
})
```

Comment: Excellent advice. I will try that out here shortly!